# HPElitebook 840 forgotten password

Tags: password-recovery, locked

I have an HP Elitebook 840 that  has a password on it. I have forgotten password. How can I recover the password and get access windows?

Comment: you can reset your microsoft account online , connect the system to internet and use the new password.

Comment: I figured it out thank you. Went into bios booted from USB and installed Windows 10.